# How to create a stable XMPP Connection in android

Tags: android

I am a beginer to  android and is currently working on a chat application using XMPP and smack. I had successfully created connection and has managed to make  chat working . But my problem is when the app become idle or in some situations (I cant trace out the exact scenario) i am not able to send/recieves messages. Please help. I am in trouble. 
Any help will be deeply appreciated.
Please Help...

Comment: What do you mean by "Stable"?

Comment: Thank you for reesponding me.....i mean it should run always so that no chat is missed. Actually i miss all the chat when i send a message after keeping device idle for sometimes. It is also not visible in ejabbered's offline message list. But i can see from the log as sent but not in ejabbered offline message.